# Access Cloud Run service in browser when authentication is required

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Docker container deployed to Cloud Run. When the Cloud Run service is set to "Allow unauthenticated invocations", I can access it without a problem.

However I only want this service to be accessible internally by our developers and other users. So, I changed the security setting on the Cloud Run service to "Require authentication."

However, now I cannot load the Cloud Run service from my web browser. It says, "Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server."

The problem is, this is happening to me even though I am logged in to the Google Cloud Console as a user with all Cloud Run permissions on this service. So how can I access the URL from my web browser and have it properly see that I have permissions?

Is it possible to use Cloud Run to host a Docker container that is only accessible to users who are logged into Google Cloud, as described above? Or am I going to have to use Identity-Aware Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run required to add an Authorization Header with an id token when you invoke it in authenticated mode. This header is not set by default by your browser (and with which identity?). Therefore, out of the box, it does not work as you experimented it.

There is 2 solutions:

- Create a frontend that use [firebase auth](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) (or [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform?hl=en)) to authenticate the user, generate an idToken and add it to the request performed to Cloud Run. it's not ideal because you must add an additional layer and register your user in Identity Platform.
- Use [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run). So you have to deploy a load balancer (and therefore pay for it) in front of your Cloud Run. IAP detect your identity from the context (your Google account) and add the required security items to be authenticated on Cloud Run. But again, it's not ideal for the developers because you does not invoke the Cloud Run service URL, but another one (or an IP if you don't have a domain name) instead.